# VBA Match Against a Column With Duplicate Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel range I'm using as a database.  The first column is sorted in ascending order by date, but there can be multiple records with the same date, e.g.

```
       A          B
1 15-Apr-2015   Carrot
2 15-Apr-2015   Yamagobo
3 16-Apr-2015   Turnip
4 17-Apr-2015   Parsnip
5 17-Apr-2015   Rutabaga
6 17-Apr-2015   Radish
7 18-Apr-2015   Daikon
```

(The stuff in column A are formatted dates, not text strings.)

What I'd like to get is the first record that has a date greater than or equal to the one I'm searching for, so I have:

```
Dim searchDate As Date
searchDate = CDate("4/17/15")
Dim searchRange As Range
Set dbRange = Worksheets("My DB").UsedRange
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.Match(CLng(searchDate), dbRange.columns(1), 1)
```

I expect v to now contain the index of the first row with 17-Apr-2015 in column A, 4.  Instead, it seems to be returning the *last* row with 17-Apr-2015, 6.

Two questions:

1) Is there a way to use Match() (or any other function) to point at the first entry that matches, instead of the last?

2) Match() freaks out if I give it a Date type as its match parameter (hence the CLng() conversion).  Is this to be expected, or am I doing something stupid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730%28v=office.11%29.aspx) instead of Match

To get the cell:

```
set MyRange = dbRange.Columns(1).Find(searchDate)
```

To get just the row:

```
MyRow= dbRange.Columns(1).Find(searchDate).row
```

Comment: Find can't do >= matches, though, can it?